# iOS can't send dictionary parameters in FBSDKGraphRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

I am trying to get the profile picture of a Facebook user in a reasonable quality from my app. By default, without any parameters, the request to the path "me?fields=picture" fetch the small one but using a parameters dictionary with the key @"type" and value @"large" would retrieve the large one. However, the api seems to be ignoring the parameters.

```
FBSDKGraphRequest* picRequest = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=picture" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"small" forKey:@"type"] HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[picRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        if (result) {

            NSString* profilePictureURLString = [[[(NSDictionary*) result objectForKey:@"picture"] objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"url"];
            NSURL* profilePictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:profilePictureURLString];
            NSData* profilePictureData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:profilePictureURL];      
       }];
```

The resulting data is always the small picture with 50x50 pixels.

Can somebody help me please? Thanks!

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the picture like picture.width(float).height(float). See the example below:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest* picRequest = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=picture.width(200).height(200)"
                                                              parameters:nil
                                                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

You can test the request into [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2C%20picture.width(200).height(200)&version=v2.7)